# Prevent view from moving on orientation change

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uikit, interface-builder

When you rotate apple's camera app, notice how none of the interface elements change position. Only the buttons on the top toolbar animate and rotate in place:

[image]

I would like to do this for my app. This view is currently defined in a storyboard, so I would prefer to use Interface Builder. How can I configure the view such that it registers an orientation change (calls the UIViewController's `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation` etc) while keeping the views in the same place?

I already know how to rotate the buttons, etc, I'm only asking about how to configure the view so it doesn't move the toolbar on an orientation change (my toolbar is currently defined as a vanilla view, not a `UIToolbar`)

Comment: Change the auto layout constraints in when you rotate orientation